# R conditional loop executes but goes haywire

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

i am trying to iterate over all the data, depending on the IF statements a new column is created. I do not get an error but the results are completely off. so it is hard for me to find the error. Any tip or suggestion is appreciated

````
```{r, echo=TRUE}
for (i in 1:length(Data)){
  if (Data$P[i]=="A")
  {
    Data$NC[i]=Data$C[i]*5
  }
  else if (Data$P[i]=="B")
  {
    Data$NC[i]=Data$C[i]*10
  }
  else if (Data$P[i]=='C')
  {
    DataNC[i]=Data$C[i]*15
  }
  else if (Data$P[i]=="D")
  {
    Data$NC[i]=Data$C[i]*20
  }
````

}

Comment: The length of a dataframe is number of columns, not number of rows. Use `nrow()`.

Comment: The problem might be related to environment. Have you checked it out? Are all your variables declared in global environment?

Comment: `Data$NC = Data$C*c(5, 10, 15, 20)[match(Data$P, c("A", "B", "C", "D"))]`

Answer (score 0):

With the data frame structure, multiplication operations like these will automatically iterate via an `ifelse()` statement, like so:

```
Data$NC <-  ifelse(Data$P == 'A', Data$C * 5, 
            ifelse(Data$P == 'B', Data$C * 10, 
            ifelse(Data$P == 'C', Data$C * 15, 
            ifelse(Data$P == 'D', Data$C * 20, 
            Data$NC))))
```

If `Data$NC` is not previously defined, and the above `ifelse()` logic does not account for all possible new values of `NC`, then you can define it with some default, like `Data$NC <- 0` before running this `ifelse()` statement